# UILabel text on each line

Tags: iphone, nsstring, uilabel

If I have a UILabel of a certain size, with line break mode set to WordWrap and numberOfLines = 0 (so it grows depending on the amount of text), is there a way to determine what characters are on each line of the label?

So if i have the text "All People Seem To Need Data Processing" as text on the label, and assuming it displays like this on screen

`All People`
`Seem To`
`Need Data`
`Processin`
`g`

is there a way to know the text on each line? or the width of each line?
Line 1 : All People
Line 2 : Seem To
Line 3 : Need Data
Line 4 : Processin
Line 5 : g

Comment: See My answer here - [How to get text from nth line of UILabel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421267/how-to-get-text-from-nth-line-of-uilabel/14413484#14413484)

Answer (score 0):

How about using NSString's sizeWithFont?  Do up to each word until you get a number bigger than the label's width.  Then chop those words and do again for the next line.

Comment: You need to account for spaces and the fact that each glyph has a different width.

Comment: to CGGraham : When word wrapping, some characters of the word get chopped like "processing" on the example

Comment: Any references as to how UILineBreakModeWordWrap works? I know if it finds certain characters like space, `?`, `-`, newline, it wraps to the next line. But how about when we have a long word?

Comment: Moshe - sizeWithFont does that (Why does enter post instead of newline in here?  Lame.) /n GianPac - If a word is longer than the width, go letter by letter.  And break your list of words on a regex of whitespace plus hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

I have given an answer regarding same query [How to get text from nth line of UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421267/how-to-get-text-from-nth-line-of-uilabel/14413484#14413484).

There is a method, Just call it. It will return an **array** of each line. Happy Coding :)