# Finding the last line of text from UILable/UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, uitextview

Here is the text present in my UILable...

"This list isn’t actually based on a straight popularity count; simply tallying the most-read verses results in a top 100 list that consists almost entirely of John 3:16 and verses from 1 Corinthians 13, Genesis 1, Romans 8, and Psalm 23. Our list instead considers instances in which BibleGateway.com users looked at three or fewer verses at one time."

How do i get the final line of text..ie.,"at three or fewer verses at one time." from my uilable.

Any solution is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you mean by line??Is it last sentence or a last few words

Comment: see this - [How to get text from nth line of UILabel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421267/how-to-get-text-from-nth-line-of-uilabel/14413484#14413484)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give one idea . May this will help you.

```
 UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,200,350)];
    myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    myLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    myLabel.text = @"This is some text in a UILabel which is long enough to wrap around the lines in said UILabel. This is a test, this is only a test.";
    [self.view addSubview:myLabel];
    CGSize labelSize = [myLabel.text sizeWithFont:myLabel.font 
                                constrainedToSize:myLabel.frame.size 
                                    lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGFloat labelHeight = labelSize.height;
    NSLog(@"labelHeight = %f", labelHeight);
    [myLabel release];
```

with above you can get height of label, then you can get the # of lines by dividing the height with some appropriate number which depends on the font size.

1) After this Get `NSAttributedString` from your `UILabel`.
2) From `NSAttributedString` you can get "\n" characters.
3) get last "\n" and extract value from this index to last index.

Comment: How do i get last "\n" now...getting 12 "\n"s for my 3 line UILable,upon displaying label.attributedText...how do i proceed?

Comment: Hey put the loop till getting 12th "\n". Fetch next String after this.

Comment: for attributed string r u using NSAttributedLabel??

Comment: how do i take out string with "\n" from label.attributetext?

Comment: Or else i also have to get into some code for this. I was giving just an idea.

Comment: Well Try + Idea !!  @NeelamVerma