# UITextView get the current line

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextfield, uitextview, uitextinput

Is there a way (crazy hacks welcome) to get the current line as a string of a UITextView? This would include word wrapping, etc. For example, in this case:

[image]

The method would return "stack overflow. Isn't it great? I" because that is the current line based on the cursor.

It could also return "This is a test I made for" or "think so", based on the position of the cursor. I have tried working with both the UITextView methods and those of UITextInput protocol.

EDIT:

Here is the code I have attempted to use. The reason I need to find the string is to get it's length, so this is why you'll see UI based code.

```
NSRange location = self.textView.selectedRange;
NSString *searchString = [self.textView.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, location)];
CGSize currentStringDimensions = [searchString sizeWithFont:self.textView.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.textView.frame.size.width, self.textView.frame.size.height) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];    
float numberOfRows = (currentStringDimensions.width/(self.textView.frame.size.width));
float left = (float)(numberOfRows - (int)numberOfRows) * (self.textView.frame.size.width);
```

This doesn't work, however. I think it might have something to with words being wrapped or the differently sized characters, but the left value is inconsistent or off after the first line.

Comment: Show the code you have tried and what it actually returned, how close have you got (I'd say `UITextInput` is the correct approach).

Comment: Will update main question with it

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421267/how-to-get-text-from-nth-line-of-uilabel/14413484#14413484

Answer (score 2):

The following code solution seem to be working. The "self" in this code refers to an instance of *UITextView*.

```
- (NSString *) getLineString:(NSRange)range
{
    NSLayoutManager *manager = self.layoutManager;

    // Convert it to a glyph range
    NSRange matchingGlyphRange = [manager glyphRangeForCharacterRange:range actualCharacterRange:NULL];

    // line fragment rect at location range
    CGRect rect = [manager lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex:matchingGlyphRange.location effectiveRange:nil];

    // obtain the line range for the line fragment rect
    NSRange lineRange = [manager glyphRangeForBoundingRect:rect inTextContainer:self.textContainer];

    // extract the string out from lineRange
    return [self.text substringWithRange:lineRange];
}

// ... later
NSLog(@"line %@", [self getLineString:self.selectedRange]);
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me (self = the UITextView)

```
func getLineString() -> String {
    return (self.text! as NSString).substringWithRange((self.text! as NSString).lineRangeForRange(self.selectedRange))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 extension version of Gil's answer:

```
extension UITextView {
    func getLineString() -> String {
        guard let text = text else { return "" }
        return (text as NSString).substring(with: (text as NSString).lineRange(for: self.selectedRange))
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using the caretRect method of UITextInput to get the offset from the left. Worked flawlessly.

Comment: @jonathanpeppers Unfortunately, I can't. This was for a paid internship I was doing the previous summer, so the code is inaccessible.

Comment: Can you re-implement the example on your own and post it? Seems like this is the point of StackOverflow, it shouldn't be the accepted answer unless it actually contains the answer.

Comment: It was such a long time ago that I really can't recall. I'll unaccept this answer though, my apologies.