# get first line from multi line label - objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uilabel, multiline

i have multiline label, it frame changes according to text length properly. when i get width of label it counts whole label width while I just want first line width.
I am  using this code to get each line.

```
NSArray *linesArray = [self getLinesArrayOfStringInLabel:label];
```

when text is too long it works properly but when text is short is breaks line's last word in second line and in label it display single line.

[image]

and array is

```
linesArray = (
    " this is multiline label. I want just first ",
    "line."
)
```

whats going wrong here??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30435406/get-string-of-first-line-in-a-uilabel

Comment: I want to know why you want that? Maybe there is another way for doing what you want...

Comment: I am using that same code ...

Comment: i want size (width )of label..

Comment: To get dynamic size of the label you can get it easily and no need to for label's number of line.

Comment: its different always as number of lines differ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get dynamic size of the label using following method

```
//label is UILabel
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [label.text boundingRectWithSize:self.view.frame.size
                                       options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                       attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Font you are using" size:<size of font>]}
                                       context:nil].size;
```

You can use size for width and height.

Comment: Please write a comment what is wrong in iy before down vote.