# Swift 3: Text alignment fails

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel

I'm trying to set my `UILabel`s textAlignment to `.right` but it does not function at all. It's like it is not even there. Here is my code:

```
let productDescriptionLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: imageViewHeight + productTitleLabel.frame.size.height + 10, width: viewWidth - 20, height: 0))
productDescriptionLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
productDescriptionLabel.textAlignment = .right
productDescriptionLabel.text = productsDescriptionArray!
productDescriptionLabel.font = productDescriptionLabel.font.withSize(self.view.frame.height * self.relativeFontConstant)
productDescriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: productDescriptionLabel.text!)
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineSpacing = 10
style.minimumLineHeight = 20
attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (productDescriptionLabel.text?.characters.count)!))
productDescriptionLabel.attributedText = attrString
productDescriptionLabel.sizeToFit()
productDescriptionLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
contentScrollView.addSubview(productDescriptionLabel)
```

All it shows is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1X5y.png)

Comment: Remove `productDescriptionLabel.textAlignment = .right`  and instead `style.alignment = .right`?

Comment: You can do it with storyboard, check out may answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45029041/text-align-last-css-property-swift-equivalent/45199912#45199912)

Comment: @inspector_60 it would be useless for the OP case, he is using `NSMutableParagraphStyle` so that won't be applicable to the label. Please note that he already did what are you mentioned in your answer programmatically by implementing `productDescriptionLabel.textAlignment = .right`. I would suggest to check my posted answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are aiming to edit the label attributed string via a `NSMutableParagraphStyle` instance (`style`) , you should assign the desired alignment to your `style`, by editing the its [`alignment`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsmutableparagraphstyle/1534368-alignment) property:

```
style.alignment = .right
```

Also, because `style` handles the alignment, there is no need to implement:

```
productDescriptionLabel.textAlignment = .right
```