# UILabel word wrapping brings extra word to next line when there is enough space for it

Tags: ios, uilabel

Under certain circumstances, UILabel seems to bring an extra word to new line even when there is enough space for it, for example,

[image]

If one more word is appended,

[image]

Even if I force the width of the label to become something like below, it still moves the word consists of "c"s to the next line,

[image]

I've tried twisting the configuration of the UILabel, but seems it behaves the same unless I set the line breaking mode to character wrap, below is the configuration for the above cases,

[image]

And the constraints (in the first two cases, the trailing ),

[image]

Is there any reason for this particular behaviour and can I fix this? It looks weird in this way leaving that space emptied.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48028047/uilabel-and-uitextview-line-breaks-dont-match/48029014#48029014

Comment: @agibson007 I see, thanks for you help!

Comment: I did find a way but I am still unsure on its reliability(resizing text) at the moment but the layout is def old UILabel. I will update those answers when I feel good about the answer.

Comment: Found any solution to it?

Comment: it seems next line should at least have two words.

Answer (score 3):

this is the default behavior since iOS 11, to fix orphaned words. No way to shut it off

**to fix it**
use the text as attributed text

**or** 
use UItextview and turn of the scroll, edit option

**or** 
use the custom label here
[Get each line of text in a UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46923039/get-each-line-of-text-in-a-uilabel/47007494#47007494)

Comment: Apart from this we can do this ans also https://stackoverflow.com/a/77344303/5622566
It really helps

Answer (score 2):

set the 'strategy' to 'Hangul word priority'. it would help

Answer (score 0):

You should set the line break to character wrap, because the letters after the space will be recognized as a word.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I know this is late but I just figured out that you can cheat the system by adding a bunch of spaces at the end of the text.

Answer (score 0):

If text of UILable may be changed,  then it's still possible to use quick-dirty hack with "\n" - new line symbol.

Text "Aaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbb cccccccccc\ndddddd" will force UILabel to display:

```
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbb cccccccccc
ddddddd
```

In Interface Builder new line can be inputted with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

If u use wordWrap, it tries to keep words in full form, as a result of this, it goes to next line. If you use character wrap, it will break on characters, and push the chars onto next line.

Answer (score -2):

For Example:-
My name is ABCXXXX and I (have space here)
love myself.

Solution:-
Use NSMutableAttributedText and write love\n. It will make the "love" be in the space myself in the next line.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).