# New line on UILabel messes with the word wrapping

Tags: swift, string, xcode, uilabel

I am trying to set the Text to UILabel as following:

```
self.lbl.text = twoLinesLongStr + "\n" + anyText
```

The number of lines are set to 0 to achieve resizing and wrapping.

The problem is on adding the \n the word wrapping for the first string is not working properly.

Here:
[image]
[image]

**In the first image why is the word "This" not on the first line?!**

Same thing happen even when using storyboard to set text:
[image]
[image]

**Reproduced:**
[image]

Comment: Oh hi matt, Its not it looks like this is the behavior. check this I think its related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940060/uilabel-word-wrapping-brings-extra-word-to-next-line-when-there-is-enough-space

Comment: you can try it urself. the constraints are good.

Comment: I edited the question. I reproduced on a new clean controller. @matt

Comment: the word "should" should be on the first line! @matt

Comment: Any ideas? :) @matt

Comment: I found this.  it's called orphan word behavior.  starting iOS 11 UILabel doesn't leave 1 word alone on a line @matt

Comment: @matt last image in question shows that. clearly

Comment: Everything that I have on that project is what u see in that last image of the question. constraint are 24 left 24 right. View as iPhone 11

Comment: text is : This is a long text that should hereee\nAny text